# AngularJs expression visible irritating

Tags: angularjs, razor

i have written angular js expression in razor for html helper but when i refresh the page after loading once it shows the expression, that is irritating.. what is the problem

here is the code

```html
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Questions.Question, new { htmlAttributes = new { ng_model = "quest" } })
    {{quest}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using curly binding expressions, you can use [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind):

```
<span ng-bind="quest"></span>
```

Or you can use [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak):

The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

```
<body ng-app="" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-cloak>
     {{ quest }}
</body>
```